# Count of patients department wise in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, group-by

```
select distinct
    Patient_Ref_master.Dept_ID as 'dept',
    Patient_Ref_master.Male_femal as 'Gender',
    count(Patient_Ref_master.Pat_ID) as 'count'
from 
    Patient_Ref_master
left join 
    Patient_Master on Patient_Master.Pat_Code=Patient_Ref_master.Pat_ID
where 
    (Patient_Ref_master.Age > 16 
     and dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 2 
     and Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02') 
    or 
    (Patient_Ref_master.Age > 16 
     and dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 1 
     and Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02') 
    or
    (Patient_Ref_master.Age >= 0 
     and Patient_Ref_master.Age <= 16 
     and dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 2 
     and Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02') 
    or
    (Patient_Ref_master.Age >= 0 
     and Patient_Ref_master.Age <= 16 
     and dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 1 
     and Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02') 
group by 
    Patient_Ref_master.Male_femal, Patient_Ref_master.Dept_ID
```

Above is my query which returns me a table as follows

```
  Dept    Gender           Count
    102    Females   3
    102    Males     4
    103    Boys          2
    103    Females   2
    103    Girls     1
    103    Males     1
    104    Females   6
    104    Males     1
```

Here I am getting count of the males,females,girls and boys according to department. But I want the output to be displayed in following manner

```
 Dept    Males Females Boys Girls 
    102    3        2     5     5  
    103    4        5     2     6   
    104    2        1     1     5
```

That is department-wise count of boys, girls, males and females. What do I have to do to get something like above pattern? `Pivot` is the option to do it? I have never used `Pivot`.

Please help.
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT    DISTINCT
              Patient_Ref_master.Dept_ID AS 'dept',
              Patient_Ref_master.Male_femal AS 'Gender',
              COUNT(Patient_Ref_master.Pat_ID) AS 'count'
    FROM      Patient_Ref_master
              LEFT JOIN Patient_Master 
                  ON Patient_Master.Pat_Code = Patient_Ref_master.Pat_ID
    WHERE    (
                  Patient_Ref_master.Age > 16 
                  AND dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 2 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02'
             )
             OR
             (
                  Patient_Ref_master.Age > 16 
                  AND dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 1 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02'
             )
             OR
             (
                  Patient_Ref_master.Age >= 0 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.Age <= 16 
                  AND dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 2 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02'
             )
             OR
             (
                  Patient_Ref_master.Age >= 0 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.Age <= 16 
                  AND dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 1 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02'
             )
    GROUP BY Patient_Ref_master.Male_femal,
             Patient_Ref_master.Dept_ID
)
SELECT     Dept,
           [Males], 
           [Females], 
           [Boys], 
           [Girls]
FROM       (
               SELECT Gender, 
                      Count ,
                      Dept
               FROM   MyCTE
           ) AS SourceTable
PIVOT
(
    MAX(Count)
    FOR Gender IN ([Males], [Females], [Boys], [Girls])
) AS PivotTable
```

The WITH MyCTE AS... block defines a Common Table Expression. It is a mean of defining something like a view on the fly. In this case i use it in order to make the code more readable. You may find more info on [Using Common Table Expressions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190766%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Then the PIVOT code is a way of transposing table rows into columns, which is in fact what you asked for. You could have omitted the CTE part and in the FROM clause of the PIVOT you could add your piece of code, but it would be somewhat unreadable. More info on PIVOT in [Using PIVOT and UNPIVOT](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)

Unfortunately the way PIVOT works, you can only define three columns in there

1. One that will be the "ID" of the result table
2. One that will contain the values you want to present as rows
3. And finally one that will contain the aggregate you need to have

So the PIVOT is just that and nothing else. But PIVOT is still a table and you may JOIN it with other tables.

As an addition i have to also make note that you may define more than one CTEs with each one containing references on the previous defined. The syntax is:

```
;WITH CTE1 AS
(
  CTE1 SELECT
)
, CTE2
(
  CTE2 SELECT ... May refer to CTE1
)
```

So, a complete answer would be something like:

```
;WITH MyCTE AS
(
    SELECT    DISTINCT
              Patient_Ref_master.Dept_ID AS 'dept',
              Patient_Ref_master.Male_femal AS 'Gender',
              COUNT(Patient_Ref_master.Pat_ID) AS 'count'
    FROM      Patient_Ref_master
              LEFT JOIN Patient_Master 
                  ON Patient_Master.Pat_Code = Patient_Ref_master.Pat_ID
    WHERE    (
                  Patient_Ref_master.Age > 16 
                  AND dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 2 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02'
             )
             OR
             (
                  Patient_Ref_master.Age > 16 
                  AND dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 1 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02'
             )
             OR
             (
                  Patient_Ref_master.Age >= 0 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.Age <= 16 
                  AND dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 2 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02'
             )
             OR
             (
                  Patient_Ref_master.Age >= 0 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.Age <= 16 
                  AND dbo.Patient_Master.Pat_Sex = 1 
                  AND Patient_Ref_master.creation_Date = '2013/08/02'
             )
    GROUP BY Patient_Ref_master.Male_femal,
             Patient_Ref_master.Dept_ID
)
,PivotCTE AS
(
    SELECT     Dept,
               [Males], 
               [Females], 
               [Boys], 
               [Girls]
    FROM       (
                   SELECT Gender, 
                          Count ,
                          Dept
                   FROM   MyCTE
               ) AS SourceTable
    PIVOT
    (
        MAX(Count)
        FOR Gender IN ([Males], [Females], [Boys], [Girls])
    ) AS PivotTable
)
SELECT    Dept,
          DeptName
          [Males], 
          [Females], 
          [Boys], 
          [Girls]
FROM      PivotCTE P
          JOIN DepartmentTable D
               ON P.Dept = D.Dept
```

Comment: Awesome, it worked. Just a small request. I am new to this pivot kind of coding. Can you please explain how the code works , I mean from line 1. Please.

Comment: 1 more thing where I need to add a code to get department name next to dept id?

Comment: Once more check my edited solution. I have also added some info, so don't just skip to the bottom. Regards, Giannis.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, `PIVOT` is the solution

```
select *
from 
     ( 
        -- your query here
     ) d
    pivot (sum([count]) for gender in (females,males,boys,girls)) p
```

Or better

```
select *
from 
     ( 
         select 
              Patient_Ref_master.Dept_ID,
              Patient_Ref_master.Male_femal,      
         from Patient_Ref_master
         left join Patient_Master on Patient_Master.Pat_Code=Patient_Ref_master.Pat_ID
         where 
             -- your filter here
     ) d
    pivot (count(pat_code) for Male_femal in (females,males,boys,girls)) p
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx